# how to display to a html twig form field value through javascript using an alert message in Symfony2?

Tags: javascript, forms, symfony, twig, alert

I would like to know how to display to a html twig form field value through javascript using an alert message in Symfony2. This is the form code:

```
     <html>
    <head>
        <title> Wkayet </title>
         <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{{asset('bundles/ikprojhome/images/icon-WKAYET.png')}}">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{asset('bundles/ikprojhome/css2/css.css')}}"/>
        <script src='{{asset('bundles/ikprojhome/lib/jquery.min.js')}}'></script> 

        <script>
            function f1(){
                alert($('#ikproj_groupebundle_eventsgroupe_start').val());
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <center>
        <div id="container">
            <div id="header">

            </div>
            <div id="content">
                <table width="100%" height="100%" align="center">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            {% for x in groupe%}
   <form id="EventForm" action='{{path('ikproj_groupe_homepaeventsAdd',{id:x['id']})}}' method="POST" {{ form_enctype(form) }} onsubmit="f1();">
   <!--<form id="EventForm" action='{{path('ikproj_groupe_homepaeventsAdd',{id:x['id']})}}' method="POST" {{ form_enctype(form) }} >-->
                                {% endfor %}
                                 {{ form_errors(form) }}
                                <table align="center">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="separation"><label for="groupname">Titre</label></td>
                                        <td>
                                     <!--<input id="titre" name="titre" required="required" type="text" size="50"/> -->
                                         <div>
                                            {{ form_errors(form.title) }}

                                            {{ form_widget(form.title) }}
                                           </div>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="separation"><label for="debut">Début</label></td>
                                        <td><!--<select id="debut" name="debut" class="select"></select>-->
                                            <div>
                                             {{ form_errors(form.start ) }}

                                             {{ form_widget(form.start ) }}
                                            </div>


                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="separation"><label for="fin">Fin</label></td>
                                        <td><!--<select id="fin" name="fin" class="select"></select>-->
                                            <div>
                                             {{ form_errors(form.end ) }}

                                             {{ form_widget(form.end ) }}
                                          </div> 

                                        </td>
                                    </tr>

                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="separation"><label for="lieu">Lieu</label></td>
                                        <td> 

                                         <div>
                                           {{ form_errors(form.location) }}

                                           {{ form_widget(form.location) }}
                                          </div>

                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td id="description" valign="top" class="separation"><label for="description">Description</label></td>
                                        <td><textarea id="ikproj_groupebundle_eventsgroupe_description" name="ikproj_groupebundle_eventsgroupe[description]" rows="5" cols="40"></textarea> 



                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td colspan="2" align="center" id="button" valign="bottom"><input class="button" type="submit" value=""/></td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                                         {{form_widget(form._token)}} 
                            </form>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table> 
            </div>
        </div>
    </center>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is the form class code:

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder

```
    ->add('title','text')
    ->add('start','datetime',array(
     'input' => 'datetime',

     'format' => 'dd/MM/yyyy H:i',
     'minutes' => array(
        0,
        30
       )
     ))
    ->add('end','datetime',array(
     'input' => 'datetime',

     'format' => 'dd/MM/yyyy H:i',
     'minutes' => array(
        0,
        30
      ) 
    ))

    ->add('location','text')
    ->add('description','text')

;
```

}

please focus on this part of JavaScript code (which is at the top of the html form code), because I tried this and it didn't work:

```
<script>
            function f1(){
                alert($('#ikproj_groupebundle_eventsgroupe_start').val());
            }
        </script>
```

So, my question is: what will be the correct code to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `id`s of dynamic form elements are auto generated in Twig, so your approach won't really work. The best way is to utilise the generated `id` in the template. It can be easily accessed via `vars` property:

```
alert( $('#{{ form.start.vars.id }}').val() );
```

Comment: well, I tried that code but it didn't work, it displays an empty alert message. However, I when I tried to display the value of the field "title" (which is a text field) using this code: `alert( $('#{{ form.title.vars.id }}').val() );` and it worked. So, it is obvious that the code doesn't work with a datetime field because the field "start" is a datetime field. Do you have any idea how to resolve that??

Comment: @NadimAkram Ah, yeah! I didn't notice that `start` is a `datetime` field. Since this field is not a `single_text` widget type, the field is compound and will have `date` and `time` subfields inside, which, as compound fields, will have `year`, `month`, `day` and `minute`, `second` subfields consequently. So, to get the selected year you should use `{{ form.start.date.year.vars.id }}` as an `id` selector. Much easier will be to use `single_text` widget type, so the field type will become `text` and you'll be able to pick the general value without digging too deep.

Comment: I got it. Well, is it possible to display the whole datetime field value?..I mean not the year apart or the minutes apart or the hours apart...etc. Just the whole datetime value.

Comment: @NadimAkram That's what I meant, you should set the `widget` type to `single_text` (read here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/datetime.html#widget), then you should be able to access date via `{{ form.start.date.vars.id }}` and time with `{{ form.start.time.vars.id }}`.